# Improve the quote appearance

Tags: feature-request

We can see online many examples of nice looking quotes, like [here](https://medium.com/@michalbohanes/seven-lessons-i-learned-from-the-failure-of-my-first-startup-dinnr-c166d1cfb8b8). However, in SO they just look like a gray background and little extra indication. So, my suggestion is:

**Make the quote block to have a left border instead of a gray background.**

Something
 along these lines
 should work

The two main reasons are:

- To use a *standard* adopted by most of the websites today, making it easier and more intuitive for the users to read quotes.
- To clearly differentiate a quote from a code block. The possible confusion can be read in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270970/938236) (it is purposefully aparently).

Comment: in before [meta-tag:status-declined]

Comment: Related: [Can we have darker <code> blocks in <blockquotes>?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270510/can-we-have-darker-code-blocks-in-blockquotes) [This answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270612/176646) recommends highlighting the left margin of block quotes (in addition to changing the background color).

Comment: [You're not the first person with this idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85892/improving-blockquote-style)

Comment: I've searched but couldn't find anything

Comment: It's hard to search for. And most of the discussion occurred before the Great Meta Schism™.