# Confusing styling of block quotes and code blocks

Tags: feature-request, design

### Problem

The styling of block quotes and code blocks on Stackoverflow are indentical on the *full site*, while on the *mobile site* they are clearly distinguishable. This is particularly noticable when there is a code block *inside* a block quote.

### Examples

1. **Code block and block quote**

   https://stackoverflow.com/a/26752510/3478852

   [image: <MSO-codeblock-blockquote-style.f-m.png>]
2. **Code block inside a block quote**

   [POSIX restrictions on pointer types in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27707048/3478852)

   [image: <MSO-codeblock-blockquote-style.2.f-m.png>]

### Proposal

I think that the blue stripe on the mobile site is *by far* superior to the gray background on the full site. I propose that the full site adopt the mobile site's styling of block quotes.

### Related

Similar suggestion by [Adriano Repetti](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1207195/adriano-repetti): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270619/3478852. I like the blue colour better, and there're already existing style rules for it on the mobile site.

Comment: There is already a restyling under way, in testing here on Meta: [Feedback Requested: Stack Overflow design update](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277200). Post feedback *there*.

Comment: In fact, there already is feedback there about blockquotes vs. code blocks, in [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277277).