# The quote color is too similar to the code color on Meta

Tags: feature-request, meta, formatting

> Usually the font for `inline code formatting` is different enough to tell that it's code`,` even when in a quote .

But did you notice that there's actually two `inline code string`s in the previous sentence? If I didn't write the sentence, I wouldn't have seen the one. In case you can't find it:

> It's the comma `:)`

There's another similar [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270510/can-we-have-darker-code-blocks-in-blockquotes) that's marked `Status-completed`. I have no clue why. Obviously, it's not really solved. Yes, code is *slightly* darker than quotes, but it's not enough.

I like to use the `formatting` when I'm adding examples of searches, or sometimes single characters like `.`. It's also good for SEDE SQL code.

It might make sense to change the color to the same color as the Similar Questions:

```css
blockquote {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF8DC;
    border-left: 2px solid #E0DCBF;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>Like this</blockquote>
```

Comment: I must be weird. I spotted the comma on the very first read. Having said that, Meta is not really the place to write code, so I don't think this needs fixing.

Comment: @Tunaki It could be your brightness settings. I can only see the code box when I tilt my screen to the extreme.

Comment: Actually, it isn't so much because of the brightness but because of the font that I spotted it ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new CSS changes have rendered this request [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). Pun intended.

Answer (score 0):

This was definitely by design, as the color scheme for meta was intended to be consistent across all formatting here.

That said, the quote mechanic is rather universal to the exchange. Each site tends to use the proposed color you show in the snippet and in my opinion **I like the standardized quote color** (#FFF8DC).

I don't really mind that the colors are the same as the code block, but I do think that it makes sense to have the quote format be standardized.

Comment: Maybe it should be changed for all meta sites, then.